# CSV-файл и матрица. Python

Tags: python, csv, матрицы

У меня есть файл в формате csv там находится матрица(вручную)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
1 3 5 7 9 7 5 3
3 1 5 3 2 6 5 7
1 7 5 9 7 3 1 5
2 6 3 5 1 7 3 2
```

Мне нужно что бы матрица прочитывалась из csv-файла и все значения матрицы менялись на ноль и уже преобразованная матрица записывалась в новый csv файл, я могу вывести содержимого файла и отдельно цифры матрицы заменить на ноль, но это получается 2 разных кода, как их объединить, так же я не могу понять как уже преобразованную матрицу записать в новый csv-файл. Помогите разобраться. Вот мои коды

```
import csv
 
with open('tekst.csv', newline='') as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

```
import numpy as p

matA = p.matrix([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2], [1,3,5,7,9,7,5,3], [3,1,5,3,2,6,5,7],[1,7,5,9,7,3,1,5],[2,6,3,5,1,7,3,2]])

print("Матрица с нулями:\n", matA * 0)
```

Comment: Это учебное задание? Какие библиотеки можно использовать?

Comment: Вариантов решения полно в общем-то от чистого питона и до `Pandas`. И всё довольно просто.

Comment: Желательно на чистом

Comment: Ну просто сделайте `split()` каждой прочитанной строки и сделайте столько нулей, сколько элементов в получившемся списке. Запишите это обратно в файл. `csv.reader` вам вообще не нужен. Или там через `,` всё-таки числа? Ну тогда делайте `split(',')`, в общем, всё просто там.

Comment: Не получается, не понимаю куда нужно `split()` добавить, а числа там без `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это буквальный ответ на вопрос. Хотя вопрос странный: зачем читать матрицу если нужны только её размеры? Но что спрошено, то спрошено:

```
# читаем матрицу (элементы целые)
m = [[int(token) for token in line.split()] for line in open('tekst.csv')]

# делаем копию того же размера из нулей
mz = [[0] * len(row) for row in m]

# записываем нули в другой файл
with open('resultat.csv', 'w') as f:
    for row in mz:
        print(' '.join(map(repr, row)), file=f)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь я понимаю мои прошлые попытки даже близко не были правильными